# Python is not recognized after cd

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, path

I am using Windows 8 64-bit. I installed Python, and see that Windows `Path` is appended by the two paths : `C:\Python27\Scripts; C:\Python27;`

So when I run `cmd` and type `python` I get the error

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I also tried `py`, same error.
I'm currently using the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17953199/2483127), so I'm typing 
`C:\Python27\python.exe manage.py runserver` for example. But this is not what I want. How can I make it work with the command `python`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have a space after the semicolon in the `PATH` value.

Comment: True, but please also recommend running just the command line `manage.py runserver`. The .py extension should either be associated with a default interpreter or the py.exe launcher (3.3+). The latter parses the script's `#!` shebang to select the target Python version.