# pydev debugger not working but can run code fine

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am using Liclipse which is basically pydev with eclipse. The python file runs fine but when I try to use the pydev debugger on the same file the debugger fails to launch and I couldn't find anything about this error. Is it a bug in pydev? It even says "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

I am using python 3.7.1

```
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Users\q4116\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.0.0.201811071259\pysrc\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 20104)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.pyx", line 134, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.set_additional_thread_info
AttributeError: '_MainThread' object has no attribute 'additional_info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.0.0.201811071259\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1951, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.0.0.201811071259\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1945, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.0.0.201811071259\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1295, in run
    self.notify_thread_created(thread_id, t)
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.0.0.201811071259\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 662, in notify_thread_created
    additional_info = set_additional_thread_info(thread)
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.pyx", line 138, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.set_additional_thread_info
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.pyx", line 147, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.set_additional_thread_info
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.pyx", line 95, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo.__init__
AttributeError: '_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo' object has no attribute 'pydev_state'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that. This is a bug in PyDev 7.0.0. I just finished uploading a new version for PyDev and LiClipse is almost there too (limiting factor is my internet connection speed, so, should be available in a few hours).

Meanwhile, removing the accelerators (and recreating if you want locally) should make it work again. i.e.: Remove _pydevd_bundle*.pyd and _pydevd_bundle\pydevd_frame_eval*.pyd and execute setup_cython.py locally (or don't if you're ok on going without the accelerator modules).

Comment: Note: LiClipse 5.1.2 is now available with the fix.

Comment: Actually, I found another critical in 5.1.2 (related to hyperlinking tracebacks) and just released PyDev 7.0.3/LiClipse 5.1.3... sorry -- please upgrade again ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after an update of these packages :

- Oomph Setup  1.11.0.v20181107-0652   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group   Eclipse Oomph Project
- PyDev for Eclipse   7.0.0.201811071319  org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group  Fabio Zadrozny
- PyDev for Eclipse Developer Resources   7.0.0.201811071319  org.python.pydev.feature.source.feature.group   Fabio Zadrozny

Not running LiClipse but just Eclipse + pydev.

I solved it for now by reverting the update. Click Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details > Installation History > Click on the last working version > Revert

I should have kept the error information though so that I could file a proper bug report ...