# How do I use use python with sublime text 3?

Tags: python, path, sublimetext3

I have installed Anaconda on Sublime Text 3 and this error pops up each time 
whenever I try to build a file:

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

If it involves adding the python to the path file(on windows), could please explain exactly what I need to add.

I use Windows 7 Ultimate, Python 3.6.0

Comment: The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-why

Comment: Adding the path is not fixing it. The path that it shows now is C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Python to the Environmental Variables.

Comment: Yes, I checked the box during installation of Python 3.6: Add python to PATH

Comment: Try to close the cmd.exe and open it again. Run this from the Command Prompt c:\python36-32\tools\scripts\win_add2path.py

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the first line of the file, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This helps the computer to identify the file and excute it using python.