# How can I solve this error of Sqlite3 with Electron?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I’ve been trying to install `sqlite3` module in electron but I always got the error message:

[image]

I tried to use the line:

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=electron --target=1.7.6 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron
```

and it returned the error on the image. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Python and [add it to your Windows Path](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables). See ['python' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17953124/3853934).

Comment: But I've alredy installed windows build tools and set python as a word od the system. when i type set python it returns python=C:\Users\mtgo0\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe