# How to add python as a command in cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> python is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file

This is the message given by cmd when I typed "PYTHON". But I have seen in the internet, many are just typing python and getting python in cmd.

Comment: *****friends say me the reason and solution as much as possible*****

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['python' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Did you typed `PYTHON` or `python` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add python address to windows path.
for windows 10, open `edit the system environment variable` click on `environment variables...` button. in user variables select `Path` and then click on `Edit` button.
click on `New` button and then `Browse` button, select python installation folder from open dialogue and click OK.

now you can test by opening a new `cmd` and typing python.