# I have trouble installing python

Tags: python, windows-10

I have installed python 3.8.1 on a windows 10 PC (and I can actually find it it the programs menu) but I can't check if it is really installed.When I run in the console "python - v" or "python --v" I get the answer "python is not a internal or external command......."
And VS code sent me the message python not installed.
 when I downloaded it and run the .exe I run a repair but still have the same issue.I have tried again to check the installation without any results.
I thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: did you add python to path?

Comment: When you install python you should checj the box that says "add to PATH", you should add it to path manually

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['python' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: please [edit] your post to add a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: No I didn't as I tought this was not recommended in python documentation. But I'll dis-install python and istall it again. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the box for "Add Python to PATH" in the installer? You can also manually [add python to path](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path). Then opening a new terminal and running "python -v" should work.

Comment: No I didn't as I tought this was not recommended in python documentation. But I'll dis-install python and istall it again. I'll get back to you. I thank you in advance for your answer.