# How to install requests module with pip?

Tags: python, path, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to install the requests module with pip, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. I open up the command prompt on windows(windows key+r,type in 'cmd' and hit enter). I have pip already installed, but when I type in 'pip install requests' to the command prompt it says

```
    C:\Users\khern>pip install requests
    'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

When I go check if pip is installed, this comes up

```
    C:\Users\khern>python -m pip --version
    'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

So, then I go to add python's path to the environment variables changing [the top part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWcHH.png) and [the bottom part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2jTN.png) so hopefully the command prompt can run python programs. But when I go to the command prompt and type python, it still says

```
    C:\Users\khern>python
    'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to programming, and just want to install the 'requests' module to finish the class I'm taking on python. Thanks!

Comment: try `pip3` instead of `pip`. It is not the module, it is the `pip` that is not working.

Comment: Did you add python to your PATH?

Comment: Can you type `python3` into command prompt? I think python will show up. If it does, then you need to add `C:\Python3.7\Scripts\ ` to the environment variables i.e. those parts you show. Then you can use `pip3 install requests`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 3):

visit this link: 
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

this will tell you how to add python to a path on windows so that you can access python from anywhere on the system.

if you need to use pip to install request:

`python -m pip install requests`

but before you run that command you have to make sure you are in pip folder, 
which generally looks something like this:
`c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip`

Answer (score 0):

The python path I think is not selected. Try reinstalling python and do this:
[solve python path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7ZJ8.png)

or this:
[solve python path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW5Xx.png)

Check out this link:
['python' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)